# VBA edit cell in master template file

Tags: vba, excel

I have a button in a template (XLT) that saves the new workbook to a directory. The filename needs to auto-increment from the one used previously. I can't rely on a directory search as the documents may be moved/deleted over time.

Is it possible to auto-increment a cell in the template file, from code running in the new workbook?

Comment: I think you'd have to directly open the template, update the value and then save it again. You can probably get your save macro to do this. If its just a single value, and your only using it from one computer, storing the value in a text file might be simpler

Answer (score 0):

As long as it is possible to save the template, you could store the value in a Name (these are most commonly used to store ranges, but can be used to store constants).

When you create the Name, just type a value instead of a range into the RefersTo area. Then you can access it like this:

```
Sub WhatsTheValue()

    Dim intValue As Integer

    intValue = Evaluate(ThisWorkbook.Names("NextValue").RefersTo)
    ThisWorkbook.Names("NextValue").Value = intValue + 1

    MsgBox intValue & vbNewLine & Evaluate(ThisWorkbook.Names("NextValue").RefersTo)

End Sub
```

The code will get the current value of the NextValue Name, assign it to the intValue variable and will immediately increment the Name.

You would, of course, have to save the template each time. This may cause problems if multiple people are accessing the template.